# javascript pseudocode practice. Basic problem solving

Tags: javascript

Could someone tell me what mistake I'm making that's causing not having the same outputs as the result.

First file:

```
function four() {
    return 4 + plus();
}

function nine() {
    return 9;
}

function plus() {

    return nine();
}

console.log(four(plus(nine())))
// Output: 13
```

Second file:

// I've added the above code into classes for demonstration purposes but it gives an error.

```
class A {
    four() {
        return 4 + plus();
    }

    nine() {
        return 9;
    }

    plus() {

        return nine();
    }
}
class B {
    constructor() {
        this.a = new A();
    }
    result() {
        console.log(this.a.four(this.a.plus(this.a.nine())))
    }
}
var r = new B();
r.result();
// Output: return nine();
           ^
ReferenceError: nine is not defined
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try: ```return this.nine()```. In JS to call another class method you must refer to the class itself... Here is some documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this